# Unable to filter json output based on date field

Tags: json, jq

I have some json data, where i need to filter the output based on given date field
from below json data i need to fetch only the block which satisfy my condition. I tried below but fetching all the fields
`cat json_data | jq "." | jq 'select(.updated_on > 2023-01-17)'`

```
{
  "comment_count": 0,
  "task_count": 0,
  "type": "pullrequest",
  "id": 3,
  "title": "Fix/adding jacoco",
  "state": "MERGED",
  "reason": "",
  "created_on": "2023-02-08T05:17:49.292686+00:00",
  "updated_on": "2023-02-08T08:55:02.565205+00:00"
}
{
  "comment_count": 0,
  "task_count": 0,
  "type": "pullrequest",
  "id": 2,
  "title": "Fix/adding jacoco",
  "state": "MERGED",
  "reason": "",
  "created_on": "2023-01-08T05:17:49.292686+00:00",
  "updated_on": "2023-01-08T08:55:02.565205+00:00"
}
{
  "comment_count": 0,
  "task_count": 0,
  "type": "pullrequest",
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Fix/adding jacoco",
  "state": "MERGED",
  "reason": "",
  "created_on": "2022-02-08T05:17:49.292686+00:00",
  "updated_on": "2022-02-08T08:55:02.565205+00:00"
}
```

Comment: Seems that you missed the quotation, just use as `jq 'select(.updated_on > "2023-01-17")' json_data` ( Btw, the filter `jq "."`  is redundant )

Comment: (Btw, `cat json_data | jq ...` is redundant, just use `jq ... json_data`)

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, strings can be compared lexicographically by jq which saves you from converting the strings to date objects first. You just need to make sure to actually use a string in the comparison:

```
select(.updated_on > "2023-01-17")
```

Output:

```json
{
  "comment_count": 0,
  "task_count": 0,
  "type": "pullrequest",
  "id": 3,
  "title": "Fix/adding jacoco",
  "state": "MERGED",
  "reason": "",
  "created_on": "2023-02-08T05:17:49.292686+00:00",
  "updated_on": "2023-02-08T08:55:02.565205+00:00"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter date:

```
$ cat json_data | jq -s 'map(select((.updated_on > "2023-01-07")))'

[
  {
    "comment_count": 0,
    "task_count": 0,
    "type": "pullrequest",
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Fix/adding jacoco",
    "state": "MERGED",
    "reason": "",
    "created_on": "2023-02-08T05:17:49.292686+00:00",
    "updated_on": "2023-02-08T08:55:02.565205+00:00"
  },
  {
    "comment_count": 0,
    "task_count": 0,
    "type": "pullrequest",
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Fix/adding jacoco",
    "state": "MERGED",
    "reason": "",
    "created_on": "2023-01-08T05:17:49.292686+00:00",
    "updated_on": "2023-01-08T08:55:02.565205+00:00"
  }
]
```

Target date:

```
$ cat json_data | jq -s 'map(.updated_on|gsub("T.*";""))'

[
  "2023-02-08",
  "2023-01-08",
  "2022-02-08"
]


$ cat json_data | jq -s 'map(select((.updated_on|gsub("T.*";"") ==  "2023-01-08")))'

[
  {
    "comment_count": 0,
    "task_count": 0,
    "type": "pullrequest",
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Fix/adding jacoco",
    "state": "MERGED",
    "reason": "",
    "created_on": "2023-01-08T05:17:49.292686+00:00",
    "updated_on": "2023-01-08T08:55:02.565205+00:00"
  }
]
```